# Simultaneous Equations.

Tags: average

Erin goes off on a long bike ride at 10km/h. One hour later her brother starts chasing after her at 16km/h. How long will it take Alistair to catch up to Erin? **Solve with simultaneous equations.**

Comment: That depends on who Alistair is... Also, what have you tried yourself? Which formulas connecting velocity, distance and time do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let time when they start be $x,y$ so $x-y=1$ now after travelling for some time y catches up erin so they have travelled same distance so $10x=16y$ solving we get $10+10y=16y$ so brother will take $5/3$ hrs which is $100mins$